# Proving continuity of a piecewise function.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I'm a university student studying mathematics. I'm currently doing a real analysis course and I'm working ahead on my problem sheet and I've arrived at this piecewise function.

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      x \cos(\frac{1}{x}) & \text{if }x \neq 0  \\
      2 & \text{if }x = 0 \\ 
   \end{cases}
$$

The question asks to prove that the function is continuous over $\mathbb{R} \backslash\{0\}$. Obviously the function breaks as it states it does at $x=0$ but barring the intuitive observation, if anyone has the rigorous technique for determining continuity of functions that would be of great help as we have not touched on it in class.

Comment: You will have some definition of continuity in your class. There are a few different facts that you'll find useful: the product of continuous functions is continuous. Polynomials are continuous. The composition of continuous functions is continuous (with some attention paid to domains of definition). These are enough to show that your function is continuous. Are you looking for something more?

Answer (score 0):

for the function to be continuous the left hand limit(LHD) must be equal to right hand limit(RHD) at x=o and also equal to f(0).

here clearly LHD and RHD tend to 0 as x approaches 0. here the function is discontinuous
at x=0.

you just need to evaluate LHD and RHD and compare them with value of function at that point.